# Deleting part of a pre-made shape in Pixelmator

Tags: pixelmator

Is it possible to delete part of one of Pixelmator's premade shapes? I tried cropping part of the shape, but that just creates a new window where the cropped portion is shown on the canvas and the rest of the shape is offscreen.

**Before**

[image]

**Intermediary**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first simple option: Right Click->Convert to Pixels and work as usual (selections and manipulation).

The second option:

Select the shape, evoke right click menu as on the picture, and choose Make Editable:
[image]

Next, you delete the part you want (select 1 anchor point and press delete - the anchor point and its surrounding points will be deleted if you press the delete button repeatedly):

[image]

UPDATE: how to create the "arc" in question.

This is my way to create your shape, probably there are others.

- Choose pen tool and make a 4-clicks shape as on the picture:
  to leave the shape "open" you click escape after 4th click.

[image]

- Create 4 additional anchor points by double clicking on the path -

[image]

- Choose 2 lower angle anchor points and press Delete -

[image]

- Select the shape and Open the Shapes panel -> click on the options button [image]

the button is on the right lower corner.

- Choose Add Shape - 
  [image]

You have this shape available - 
[image]

Now, work with this shape us usual, but set the fill to NONE:

[image]

Comment: I used your second of convert to pixel because when I delete the anchor points it still connects 2 of anchor points that I don't want it to. The problem now is that the shape doesn't scale properly. Is there a way to convert back to shape/vector?

Comment: Could you please place the screenshot of the shape before and after the operations - what do you want to get?

Comment: I added the before, intermediary, and after pictures. In the intermediary step, I delete the 2 anchors at the very top (one is red and the other is white because it's highlighted.

Comment: @Auser and what do you want to achieve at the end? Could you convert the original shape, please, end erase the undesired part to allow me to see the final image you want?

Comment: @Auser I know how to create the shape you want and to make it accessible all the time... But it is not straightforward method :) - do you want me to proceed and place all the step in the answer? It is a little bit strange, however it works

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you don't mind =D

Comment: @Auser actually I did it: will upload now. hold on

Comment: thanks so much for this solution. I wish I could upvote multiple times :)

Comment: @Auser the solution is not perfect, however from this example you should learn some things :)

Answer (score 0):

Ilan is spot on.

If you are still finding it difficult, we created a tutorial to show you how to create and edit Pixelmator shapes, which might come in handy.
http://www.pixelmatortemplates.com/pixelmator-tip-22-how-to-create-and-edit-shapes-the-basics/

PN.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! It's alright to link to your own site, but just a heads up on a couple things: please be sure to always make a note that the site you are linking to is yours (as you have done here). It's also helpful to include a summarized version of what you're linking to in the event that your site goes down. In this case I don't see it as much of an issue since you noted that Ilan's answer provides the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I should add another more valuable solution to the creation of the U shape as well as any other shape you want to create.

Every shape is actually a surface surrounded by stroke. My previous solution was based on tricking the "stroke" instead of creating full value shape.

If any shape is an outline, thus the solution is to create an outline and work with it as with usual shape:

Instead of creating a stroke-based shape, we create an outline-based shape by pen tool (similar as I described previously) -

[image]

Next, the "rounding" is straightforward via creation anchor points and deletion of redundant -

[image]

Final shape outline - fully editable, can have a stroke and can be operated as usual shape -

[image]